# Which method to solve this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$x'=(x+t+1)^2$$

I need to solve this differential equation but do not know how. We cannot use separation of variables so my only guess here would be to use an integrating factor but how would I find that?

EDIT:
the official answer is $x(t) = −t − 1 + \tan(t + C)
$

EDIT2:
subsituting $y = x + t +1$ yielding $y'+1 = y^2$ and integrating
$$\int \frac{dy}{y^{2}+1} = \int dt $$
$$ \arctan(y)=t+C$$
$$ \tan(t+C) = y $$
$$ x+t+1=\tan(t+C)$$
$$ x(t) = \tan(t+C) -t-1$$

Which is the answer

Comment: What do you mean when you say we cannot. You may not use it or you don't know how to use it?

Comment: The course says it isn't possible for $ x′=(x+t+1)^2 $ but that it is possible for $(y = x + t + 1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $y= x+t+1$ then you have $$y'-1 = y^2$$

So we have $$\int {dy\over y^2+1} = \int dt$$

Can you do it know?

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $$x+t+1=u$$ then $$x'+1=u'$$